# how to use preventDefault() with paste event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, i have a validation on TextBox to prevent the user to input the data more than 10 characters, i have applied the validation on keyprees but i am not able to restrict the user to paste the data with length more than 10.
i have searched and try paste event but its not working its not restricting the user to paste the value, preventDefault(); is not working.

code-

```
$('#EMName').bind('paste', function (e) {
        var self = $(this);
        var v = false;
        var flag = setTimeout(function () {

            var len = $(self).val().length;
            if (len > 10) {
                alert("false");
                v = false;
                return false
            }
            else {
                alert("true");
                v = true;
                return true;
            }

        }, 0);
        if (v == false)
            e.preventDefault();   
});
```

Comment: bind('paste') is not a keypress. It is crtl+v [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kgcE/8/)

Comment: It's hard to do this in crossbrowser way

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem we experienced with our applications as well. It's not just pasted text, it's also various browser plugins that will pre-fill fields for you or stored form data in the browser itself that will not fire up any event.

The only way we were able to overcome this is to make a periodic checks with setInterval(), so we did not miss these events.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you actually wont to allow the user to Paste. If you don't the below will work

```
<input id="EMName" value="" onpaste="return false" maxlength="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to monitor as many events as you can for that input that allow the value to be changed. I use something similar on one of my websites, and this is what I do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').on('propertychange keyup input paste', function(){
        var target = $(this);
        var text = target.val();
        if (text.length > 10) {
            target.val(text.substring(0, 9));
        }
    });
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8U8ZK/2/)

This works for typing, ctrl+v, right-click paste and most other things. I'm not sure if it will work if a browser plugin populates it.

Comment: a question - if you are sure it works, have you tried it? we did and a plugin filling the form did not fire ANY event at all

Comment: There is a demo link for you to try. Like I said in my answer : This works for typing, ctrl+v, right-click paste and most other things. I'm not sure if it will work if a browser plugin populates it.

Comment: lol, sry man, I read "I'm sure it will work if a browser plugin..." ... apologies